# Ruby On Rails Devise gem conflict error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

```
C:\Users\Prabal\Desktop\rails-club>rails generate devise member
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 5.1.0)

In Gemfile:
    railties (~> 5.1.0) x64-mingw32

```
devise (~> 4.2.1) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  railties (< 5.1, >= 4.1.0) x64-mingw32

devise (~> 4.2.1) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  responders x64-mingw32 was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
    railties (< 5.1, >= 4.2.0) x64-mingw32
```

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

I am a newbie in ROR please help me how to move on to next step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `devise v4.2.1` gem with `rails v5.1.0`. It is not possible to do so at this moment as `devise v4.2.1` has a [runtime dependency](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/4.2.1) of `railties = <5.1, >=4.1.0` and `rails v5.1.0` has a [runtime dependency](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/5.1.0) of `railties = 5.1.0`. End result is a **version conflict** which is what you are encountering. I would suggest you to downgrade to `rails v5.0.2` in order to be able to use `devise` on your app. There shouldn't be any version conflicts once you do that.